# Как заменить <div> на другой тег и/или атрибут class из всех тегов <div> средствами PHP?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Спарсил информацию.

Получил несколько строк, которые содержат текст, обрамленный в теги с классами, хочу их либо заменить либо удалить.

Как это можно сделать, чтобы не пострадал текст?

Первая строка:

```
<div class="cm-par-large">Это пример первого текста, где нужно заменить обрамляющий div с классом на обычный <p></div>
```

Должно получиться так:

```
<p>Это пример первого текста, где нужно заменить обрамляющий div с классом на обычный</p>
```

Следующая строка

```
<div class="cm-par-medium wysiwyg-component"> <p style="line-height: 19.2pt; margin: 0cm 0cm 15.0pt 0cm;"><span>Это пример второй строки из которой нужно удалить обрамляющие дивы но не трогать p span</span></p>
</div>
```

Она же на выходе:

```
<p style="line-height: 19.2pt; margin: 0cm 0cm 15.0pt 0cm;"><span>Это пример второй строки из которой нужно удалить обрамляющие дивы но не трогать p span</span></p>
```

В голове только идея перебрать все `div`, извлечь из них тексты и обернуть при необходимости в нужные теги, но как-то это сложновато, может быть, есть какая-то регулярка, которая позволяет удалять края, но не трогать содержимое?

Comment: дак не хотите просто у дивов классы убрать?

Comment: @teran так нафига мне эти дивы, лишний html в тексте.. мне бы только абзацы оставить и прочие теги которые отвечают чисто за грамматическую часть (что ли). Так то мне и дивы с классами не принципиальны, но хотелось бы на выходе чистый текст иметь (без лишних оберток, которые на текущем сайте никакой нагрузки не несут)

Comment: Крайне желательно делать такое не регулярками, а нормальным html-парсером

Comment: @andreymal использовал phpQuery получил текст в таком виде, что в примере выше, но далее мне нужно как раз заменить (удалить) лишние обертки

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов не знаю, что умеет phpQuery, но почти наверняка для php можно найти полноценные библиотеки для работы с html, которые могут создавать, изменять и удалять html-элементы на любой вкус

Comment: @andreymal выборка элементов классов, атребутов аналогична jquery, если jq такое умеет то эта справится (кстати довольно удобная библиотека) на ютубе есть русскоязычное видео с описание ее возможностей.
документация по работе (если будет интересно): https://code.google.com/archive/p/phpquery/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот вам пример, изучайте:

```
<?php

$string = '<div class="cm-par-large">Это пример первого текста, где нужно заменить обрамляющий div с классом на обычный </div>

    Текст без тегов.

    <div class="cm-par-medium wysiwyg-component"> <p style="line-height: 19.2pt; margin: 0cm 0cm 15.0pt 0cm;"><span>Это пример второй строки из которой нужно удалить обрамляющие дивы но не трогать p span</span></p>
</div>
';

// Массив с regex шаблонами 
// (добавлен модификатор "x" для комментирования внутри шаблонов)
$pattern = [
    // 1-й шаблон для поиска и замены текста в контейнерах <div> :
    '~
        <(div)[^>]*> # Ищет <div(тут любой не обязательный текст)>
            (.+?)    # Ищет любой текст (вхождение символов тут обязательно)
        </\1>        # Ссылка на подмаску №1 (эквивалентно имени тега "div")
    ~x',
    // 2-й шаблон для поиска и замены тегов <div> :
    '~
        <(div)[^>]*> # Ищет <div(тут любой не обязательный текст)>
            |        # Оператор ветвления (ИЛИ)
        </(?1)>      # Рекурсивная ссылка на подмаску №1 (эквивалентно имени тега "div")
    ~x'
];
// Массив значений для подстановки 
$replace = ['<p>$2</p>', ''];

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $string);
```

Comment: А можете немного комментарием сопроводить?) не все моменты понятны, я про регулярки читал и какие то простые вещи понимаю.
Но вот что за две части в переменной $pattern, что-то совсем не похоже на пару из открывающего и закрывающего тега, тем более что у последнего и атрибутов то никаких нет)

Comment: @Евгений Шевцов хорошо, только чуть позже - я комментарии пропишу в своём ответе.

Comment: спасибо, так и хотел)

Comment: @Евгений Шевцов добавил каменты. Честно говоря, проще было  написать шаблоны, чем сформулировать к ним описание )

Answer (score 1):

Если вам не нужно удалять атрибуты во всех возможных воображаемых случаях, то можно сделать совсем просто:

```
$result = preg_replace('#<div[^>]+>#i', '<div>', $string);
```

Помните, что парсить HTML регулярками - это дорога в ад.

Comment: нет, я с помощью этой библиотеки парсил https://code.google.com/archive/p/phpquery/
а это уже конечный результат, который нужно было очистить от лишнего